# How to i write unit test with xUnit for this cqrs?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, xunit

```
public class UserCommandHandler : IUsersCommandHandler
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;
    private readonly ILogger<UsersCommandHandler> _logger;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfwork;
    private readonly IRepository<Users> _usersRepository;

    public UsersCommandHandler(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory, ILogger<UsersCommandHandler> logger, IUnitOfWork unitOfwork, IRepository<Users> userRepository)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceScopeFactory));
        _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        _unitOfwork = unitOfwork ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(unitOfwork));
        _userRepository = usersRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userRepository));


    }

    
    public async Task<CreateUserResponseModel> Handle(CreateUserModel request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Users entity = request.ToEntity();
        Users addedEntity = _userRepository.Insert(entity);
        await _unitOfwork.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken);
        CreateUserResponseModel model = addedEntity.ToModelCreate();
        return model;    


    }
}
```

Can someone please help me how to write an unit test with xUnit for this? Im so stuck.

I try to write an unit test but i cant, i need a solution

Comment: what kind of databases do you use ? sql server or mongo db or .....?

Comment: if you use repository for your Handle no need to use _unitOfwork inside of your Handle , just build a method for _userRepository to save changes so you can call it like this _userRepository.SaveChanges()

Comment: if you are using EF core and repository , it's not necessary to use unitOfWork in your project

Comment: @regestea23 this is not my projecy, i am an intern and that project given to me and i have to write an unit test for this but i cant

Answer (score 0):

you didn't provide any required information, so i guess the codes inside of UnitOfWork and UserRepository and you need to change this test

I pass ServiceScopeFactory and Logger as null because we didn't use it in Handel

overall, the test is something like this

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Moq;
using Xunit;

public class UserCommandHandlerTests
{

        private readonly DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> dbContextOptions;

        private MyDbContext _inMemoryDbContext;

        public UserCommandHandlerTests()
        {
            dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "MyDatabaseName")
                .Options;
        }


    [Fact]
    public async Task UserCommandHandler_Should_AddUserToDatabase()
    {
        // Arrange

        _inMemoryDbContext = new MyDbContext(dbContextOptions);

        var unitOfWork=new UnitOfWork(_inMemoryDbContext);

        var userRepository=new Repository<User>();

        var userCommandHandler=new UserCommandHandler(null,null,unitOfWork,userRepository);

        var createUserData=new CreateUserModel()
        {
            Id=Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name="fake name"
        };

        // Act
        var createUserResponse  =await userCommandHandler.Handle(createUserData);

        var user=await _inMemoryDbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=>x.Id==createUserData.Id);

        // Assert
        Assert.NotNull(createUserResponseModel);
        Assert.NotNull(user);
        Assert.IsType<CreateUserResponseModel>(createUserResponse);
        Assert.IsType<User>(user);

        // Clean
        _inMemoryDbContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

also you need to use Mock in your tests this Link can help you  https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-simplify-your-csharp-unit-testing-mocking-framework